# Angular2 HTTP response error

Tags: angular

I have weird problem with getting data from json file. I dont know why it not working, one thing I can say is popular "it has worked before".  I getting error: GET http://localhost:4200/apidata/femaleModels.json 404 (Not Found). Can somebody look at my code and check whats wrong, maybe I forgot about something?

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpModule  } from '@angular/http';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { GalleryComponent } from './gallery/gallery.component';
import { TeamDemonstrationComponent } from  './gallery/teamDemonstration/teamDemonstration.component';
import { PersonalDemonstrationComponent } from './gallery/personalDemonstration/personalDemonstration.component';


@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        GalleryComponent,
        TeamDemonstrationComponent,
        PersonalDemonstrationComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpModule
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

export class AppModule { }

modelsService.ts:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core'
import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class ModelsService {
private _femaleModelsUrl: string = "apidata/femaleModels.json";
private _maleModelsUrl: string = "apidata/maleModels.json";
private _premiumModelsUrl: string = "apidata/premiumModels.json";

constructor(private _http: Http) {}

    getFemaleModels() {
        return this._http.get(this._femaleModelsUrl)
            .map( (response: Response) => response.json() );
    }
}
```

gallery.component.ts

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { ModelsService } from './modelsService/models.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-gallery',
    templateUrl: './gallery.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./gallery.component.scss'],
    providers: [ModelsService],
})
export class GalleryComponent implements OnInit {

    models: modelInterface[];
    demonstrationType: string = 'team';
    femaleModels: any;


    constructor(private _modelsService: ModelsService) {}
    ngOnInit() {
        this._modelsService
            .getFemaleModels()
            .subscribe( responseFemaleModelsData => this.femaleModels = responseFemaleModelsData );
    }
}


export interface modelInterface {
    name: string;
    height: number;
    size: string;
    hair: string;
    eyes: string;
    shoeSize: number;
    dateOfBirth: number;
    imgDir: string[];
}
```

files tree:

[image]

Comment: All the code you posted is irrelevant. The error tells you that the **server** doesn't have any resource /apidata/femaleModels.json. I'm guessing you're using angular CLI. Here's how you configure it to serve static resources: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-asset-configuration

Comment: Please use the complete path url relative from the index.html like `../../../src/app/data/apidata/femaleModels.json`

Comment: Check out this link https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: @JB Nizet Thank YOU!!!!!!